# React Router not showing the component

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-router

I've been learning reactjs for few weeks now and I wanted to create a small blog type website. So there are a few problems with my app.

1. First of all, I want the inactive sidebar button to look completely merged with white color with the font color to black and to have the inset box-shadow only when it's clicked and active.
2. Same with the main container navigation panel where ALL and Shared with Me should be grey but turns black and big in font size when clicked but it doesn't do anything when clicked.
3. The third is that when I click "Post" in the navigation panel then it should show the hello button and when I click the "ALL" button, it should just show hello in the main area but it isn't working as well as both the hello button and the hello text are shown in default but I want to show the hello text when I click "All" button. Not sure if it's the problem with react-router or some other thing. I knew how to show components only when clicked but I forgot it since I didn't practice enough or write it down and I'm going insane now. If someone could please point me in the correct direction, I would be very grateful.

I have put the demo in code sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-feynman-2tvy5

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import NavBarPage from "./nav";
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css";
import Home from "./Home";
import About from "./About";
import NoMatch from "./NoMatch";
import Layout from "./component/Layout";
// import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import LeftBox from "./component/leftBox";
import SecTab from "./component/secTab";
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <>
          <NavBarPage />
          {/* <hr /> */}
          {/* <LeftBox /> */}
          <Layout>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
              <Route path="/about" component={About} />
              <Route path="/secTab" component={SecTab} />
              <Route Component={NoMatch} />
            </Switch>
          </Layout>
        </>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

leftBox.js (the left sidebar)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Link } from "react-router-dom";

import { Nav, Button } from "react-bootstrap";

import "../App.css";
export default class LeftBox extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="nav">
          <ul>
            <li className="list-item">
              <Link to="/about">
                <input
                  type="button"
                  className="sideButton sideBarText"
                  value="Dashboard"
                />
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li className="list-item">
              <Link to="/">
                <input
                  type="button"
                  className="sideButton2 sideBarText2"
                  value="People"
                />
              </Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

textBox.js (The main area navigation panel)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import WriteSec from "./writeSec";
import SecTab from "./secTab";
import { BrowserRouter as Link } from "react-router-dom";

class TextBox extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div class="container" id="dashboardpills">
          <br />

          <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <span class="active mainCom" id="hometab" data-target="#home">
                POSTS
              </span>
              <WriteSec />
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <span
                id="sharedwithmetab"
                class="nav-link mainComS2"
                data-toggle="pill"
                data-target="#menu2"
              >
                <Link to="/secTab">All</Link>
              </span>
              <SecTab />
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <span
                id="sharedwithmetab"
                class="nav-link mainComS"
                data-toggle="pill"
                data-target="#menu2"
              >
                SHARED WITH ME
              </span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TextBox;
```

Layout.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Container, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import LeftBox from "./leftBox";
import "../App.css";
import TextBox from "./textBox";
class Layout extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Container className="conMain">
        <Row>
          <Col xs={3} className="leftMain">
            <LeftBox />
          </Col>
          <Col xs={9} className="rightMain">
            <TextBox />
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
export default Layout;
```

App.css

```
.leftMain {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding-top: 40px;
}
.rightMain {
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
.navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0.7rem 2rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 88.15%;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  border-bottom: solid 1px var(--primary-color);
  opacity: 0.9;
  position: static;
  top: 0;
  box-shadow: 12px 0 15px -4px rgba(31, 73, 125, 0.8),
    -12px 0 8px -4px rgba(31, 73, 125, 0.8);
  box-shadow: 0 9px 0px 0px white, 0 -9px 0px 0px white,
    12px 0 15px -4px rgba(31, 73, 125, 0.8),
    -12px 0 15px -4px rgba(31, 73, 125, 0.8);
}

.navbar ul {
  display: flex;
}
.navbar a {
  color: #2076d9;
  padding: 0.45rem;
  margin: 0 0.25rem;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  color: var(--primary-color);
}

.navbar .welcome span {
  margin-right: 0.6rem;
}
/* dashButton {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
dashButton::after {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
} */

@media (min-width: 768px) #dashboardpills .nav-item .nav-link {
  max-height: 42px;
  opacity: 0.25;
  color: #000;
  font-family: Poppins;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 42px;
}
a:not([href]):not([tabindex]) {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.nav-pills .nav-link {
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}
.nav-link {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
}
a {
  color: #007bff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}
*,
::after,
::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
user agent stylesheet li {
  text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
}
.nav {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.sideButton {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  font: inherit;
  color: inherit;
  border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
  background-color: rgba(191, 191, 191, 0.14);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px -1px 28px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px -1px 28px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17);
  box-shadow: inset 0px -1px 28px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.sideButton:active {
  background-color: #007bff;
}
.sideButton:selected {
  background-color: #007bff;
}

.sideButton2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 55px;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  font: inherit;
  color: inherit;
  border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px -1px 28px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px -1px 28px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17);
  box-shadow: inset 0px -1px 28px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.sideButton2:active:after {
  background-color: rgba(191, 191, 191, 0.14);
}
.titleName {
  font-family: Poppins;
}

.sideBarText {
  color: #000;
  font-family: Poppins;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 25px;
}
.sideBarText2 {
  color: #000;
  font-family: Poppins;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 25px;
}

.createNew {
  height: 40px;
  width: 153px;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 10px;

  background-image: linear-gradient(
    to top,
    #d83f91,
    #d0409b,
    #c743a5,
    #bb47af,
    #ae4bb8
  );
  box-shadow: 0 2px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
.signOut {
  border: 0px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    to right,
    #eb3941,
    #f15e64,
    #e14e53,
    #e2373f
  );
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(242, 97, 103, 0.4);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.mainCom {
  height: 56px;
  width: 68px;
  color: #000;
  font-family: Poppins;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 56px;
  left: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.mainComS {
  height: 42px;
  width: 255px;
  opacity: 0.25;
  color: #000;
  font-family: Poppins;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 42px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.mainComS2 {
  height: 42px;
  width: 200px;
  opacity: 0.25;
  color: #000;
  font-family: Poppins;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 42px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.conMain {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 12px 0 15px -4px rgba(31, 73, 125, 0.8),
    -12px 0 8px -4px rgba(31, 73, 125, 0.8);
  box-shadow: 0 9px 0px 0px white, 0 -9px 0px 0px white,
    12px 0 15px -4px rgba(31, 73, 125, 0.8),
    -12px 0 15px -4px rgba(31, 73, 125, 0.8);
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For react dom version 6, I used `element` instead of `component` and it worked for me.
Here we don't need to mention `exact`.

For example :

```
<Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />}/>
    <Route path="/add-course" element={<Addcourse/>} exact />
    <Route path="/view-courses" element={<Allcourses/>} exact />
</Routes>
```

Comment: thanks a lot man! you just saved me.

Answer (score 2):

you've asked many questions into one. I will not answer the CSS part here. I'll focus on the `react-router` part of the question.

From **App.js**

```
<Layout>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/about" component={About} />
    <Route path="/secTab" component={SecTab} />
    <Route Component={NoMatch} />
  </Switch>
</Layout>
```

The `<Switch>` component is responsible for render the different components for each route. But the problem here is that you are rendering it as a child of your `<Layout>` component. And your `<Layout>` component is doing nothing about it. It's just skipping it completely.

From **Layout.js**

```
    return (
      <Container className="conMain">
        <Row>
          <Col xs={3} className="leftMain">
            <LeftBox />
          </Col>
          <Col xs={9} className="rightMain">
            <TextBox />
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    );
```

See that it does nothing with its `this.props.children` prop. So nothing from your `<Switch>` is being rendered.

Suggestion for **Layout.js**

```
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
      <Container className="conMain">
        <Row>
          <Col xs={3} className="leftMain">
            <LeftBox />
          </Col>
          <Col xs={9} className="rightMain">
            <TextBox />
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
      {this.props.children}    // THIS WILL RENDER YOUR <Switch>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
```

The 1 and 2 topics of your question are probably more related to CSS and I suggest you move them to a different question.

Comment: it's showing the Home page. and in a place where it shouldn't be shown. I want to show those props only when we click posts, all or shared with me. also not the default home or about components but sectab. there should be a way to it right? I updated the codesandbox, i hope you understand the problem that i'm conveying

Comment: I suggest you break down your problems into smaller items so you can isolate them and ask for specific help on each one of them. In my answer you can see why React router wasn't rendering your components based on route.

Comment: I have no idea how I would break the router problem to smaller bit. Can you just help me with the router problem only? like why it's showing the home component on loading. Even if I remove the home component then when I click on the logo on the navbar then it won't direct to the main page so removing the home component is also not an option. My problem is that I want to show a specific component when I click on any of the button on the navigation panel and that it's positioned under the navigation panel and not to the side of the navigation panel. please help me out. I've been stuck for a week

Comment: I removed (commented) the `TextBox`. See if this is doing what you want. It's not showing under it anymore. https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-jang-c8h0h

Comment: Okay, the sidebar is working but I want home, about, stuff to show within the layout and also when I click POST then the home component should be shown, when I click all then sectab should be shown. It'd be same as you did with the sidebar but I want all of them to show within layout.js component under the POST, ALL, SHARED WITH ME tabs.

Comment: like in stackoverflow, you see the sidebar, if we click tags then all kinds of tags would be shown in the middle area of the website, right. and also if you click on the products of the navbar then it would also show in the middle area of the layout so that's exactly what I want with my app. No matter where I click, sidebar, navbar or the navigation panel in the layout component, everything should be shown in the layout component or the middle area of the app.. I'm sorry if I can't phrase my questions correctly. English is not my first language

Comment: That what I was telling you before. This is not a problem related to `react-router`. It's related to `import { Container, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";` and it's directly related to CSS. I suggest you write another question specifically for that. And if you really need a deep understanding and full control over the CSS of your page, I would suggest you'd take a look into `styled-components` and build your own styled components, instead of using bootstrap ones that will serve well for a default common case use, but may be a pain if you need to customize them.

Comment: so it's not possible with bootstrap? even without using bootstrap, can't I use the textBox.js file stuff, i mean the navigation panel. I don't care about bootstrap if I'm getting the navigation panel of POST, ALL, Shared with me tabs and the contents under it. I used bootstrap only for styling some buttons and dividing the sidebar and the main area columns into 3 and 9 cols. can you just show me how to use the navigation panel too with the tabs & contents under it. Also thanks for giving your time for the solution till now. I really appreciate that

Comment: It's probably doable with `react-bootstrap`, you just need to take a deeper dive on how its components work and behave to combine them and maybe extends their CSS's to fit your needs. I just wanted to let you know that depending on your needs (current and future), it might be useful to learn some more CSS so you can build your own solutions and have more flexibility. I chose to learn CSS and `styled-components` instead of bootstrap. The learning curve is steeper but once you're done, you can do pretty much anything and not have to rely on pre-build components that may be hard to customize.

Comment: I mean, `bootstrap` is excellent to get a prototype up and running in no time. But the caveat is that when you need something that doesn't come out of the box, it might be a pain to adapt it to fit your needs. I don't know if this is case on this exact problem of yours. It might be easy to do with `bootstrap` But it's something to think about.

Comment: Okay, I get you. But there should be at least a way to show the react router components in the main middle area under the navigation panel(not the navbar). Like I click POST and the secTab or about should be shown under the navigation panel. I added the {this.props.children} under the <COL> and above <ROW> but it isn't showing properly. There should be at least one way to do it I guess